# Right click datatable row to get context menu popup and row's first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I need to write code that, on right-clicking a row in my datatable, two things happen: a context menu pops up, and that row's first cell is retrieved so I can pass it to my Ajax.

Right now, I have code that, when you left click a row, the first cell's contents are retrieved. I also wrote the context menu code, so that when you right click, it pops up. However, I need to combine these, so that the right click does both.

Hope that makes sense. I'm still pretty new to Javascript/jQuery/Ajax. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#tasksTable').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "className": "dt-left", "targets": "_all" }
        ],
        select: true
    });

    $('#tasksTable tbody')
        // on left click, get/print row data
        .on('click', 'tr', function () { // on row click, get data in array form
            console.log(table.row(this).data()[0]);
        })
        // show lock/unlock window popup on right click
        .bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
            $(".context-menu").hide(); // hide old window if open
            var id = this.id;
            $("#txt_id").val(id);
            var top = e.pageY + 5;
            var left = e.pageX;
            $(".context-menu").toggle(100).css({
                top: top + "px",
                left: left + "px"
            });
            
            //clickedRowId = this.textContent[0];
            //console.log('You clicked a row with the task ID: ' + clickedRowId);
            
            return false;
        });

    // hide lock/unlock window when clicking elsewhere
    $(document).bind('contextmenu click', function () {
        $(".context-menu").hide();
    });

    // Lock row selection
    $(".lockTask").click(function () {
        LockTaskToggle(clickedRowId); // get task id of this row for ajax
    });

    // Unlock row selection - might not need after all
    $(".unlockTask").click(function () {

    });

    //LoadTasksAjax();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="tasksTable" class="display compact hover" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="datarow">

            <!--
            <th>Locked</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            -->
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>  
            <th>Locked By</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>      
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the context menu code in the drawCallback of your table initializer. This will get you an object representing the row, then call row.data() to get the object representing the cell values. If it is just an array get the values by data[index], if it is a json object get the values using property names.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#tasksTable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "className": "dt-left", "targets": "_all" }
    ],
    select: true,
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows().nodes();
        
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '#tasksTable tbody tr',
            trigger: 'right',
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var row = table.row(options.$trigger)
                var data = row.data();

                switch (key) {
                    case 'copy-cell-1':
                        navigator.clipboard.writeText(data[0]); 
                        alert(`I copied ${data[0]} to the clipboard`);
                        break;
                    case 'copy-cell-2':
                        navigator.clipboard.writeText(data[1]); 
                        alert(`I copied ${data[1]} to the clipboard`);
                        break;
                    default :
                        break;
                }
            },
            items: {
                "copy-cell-1": {name: "Copy first cell to clipboard", icon: "copy"}, //you can use dataTables icons (ie. copy) or fontawesome classes for the icon
                "copy-cell-2": {name: "Copy second cell to clipboard", icon: "fa-copy"},
            }
        })

    }
});
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghq9ex82/)